# Python Django Forms Multiple Select HTML Ouput

Tags: python, django-forms

I'm trying to output the description field from my model
in a django form without joy.

After searching around and not finding what I need
I hope I can ask here.

Here is my models, form, template and template output.
I've abrieviated to help make this post concise.

I'm working on the view in this project so the model
has been designed by someone else and I can't really change it.

MODELS:

1)

```
from django.db import models  

class Project(models.Model):  
    description = models.TextField(blank = True)  
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, blank = True)  

     def __unicode__(self):
        """ String representation of projects. """
        return unicode(self.name)
```

2)

```
from django.db import models

class Share(models.Model):

    description = models.TextField    
    last_access = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    location = models.URLField(verify_exists = False)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', related_name = 'shares')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.location)
```

FORM:

```
from django import forms
from models import Share

class ExportForm(forms.Form):  
    ps = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Share.objects.filter(project=1),widget=forms.SelectMultiple())
```

VIEW:

```
form = ExportForm()
```

TEMPLATE:

I have this to ouput the multiple select bos:

```
{{ form.ps }}
```

TEMPLATE OUTPUT:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="ps" id="id_ps">  
<option value="11">Share object </option>  
<option value="10">Share object </option>
</select>
```

I've tried several things from searching around but can't
seem to be able to make the 'description' field in there  rather than 'Share object'

Any advise much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to change the `__unicode__` method of the Share model to return description instead of location, but since you say you can't change the model you will need to  subclass `ModelMultipleChoiceField` and override the `label_from_instance` method.

```
class MyModelMultipleChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.description
```

This is explained [in the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield).

Comment: Based on the output, it doesn't even look like the displayed `__unicode__` method is being called. If it were, there would be urls in the `<option>` tags. right?

Comment: from django import forms
from models import Share

class MyModelMultipleChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
  return obj.description
   
class ExportForm(forms.Form):
    ps = MyModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Share.objects.filter(project=1))